# Wrong pointers in C?

Tags: c, pointers, function-pointers

I have five vectors and I'm changing their values in this function

Headers:

```
char *lfsr(char *bin);    
char *saveToArray(FILE *hexFile);
char *hexToBinary(char *hex);
```

I change their values like this:

```
FILE *hexFile = fopen("hex.txt", "rb"); //recebido pela consola
char *seed;
char *x0, *y0, *z0, *dT0;

seed = saveToArray(hexFile);

x0 = hexToBinary(seed);

y0 = lfsr(x0);

z0 = lfsr(y0);

dT0 = lfsr(z0);
```

This is lfsr function:

```
char* lfsr(char *bin)
{
    //bits significativos para fazer o xor 128 -> 128,126,101,99;
    int bits[4];
    int bit;

    if(bin[0] == '0')
        bits[0] = 0;
    else if(bin[0] == '1')
        bits[0] = 1;

    if(bin[2] == '0')
        bits[1] = 0;
    else if(bin[2] == '1')
        bits[1] = 1;

    if(bin[21] == '0')
        bits[2] = 0;
    else if(bin[21] == '1')
        bits[2] = 1;

    if(bin[19] == '0')
        bits[3] = 0;
    else if(bin[19] == '1')
        bits[3] = 1;

    bit = bits[0] ^ bits[1] ^ bits[2] ^ bits[3] ^ 1;
    //reconstruir o vector de char depois do lfsr
    for(int i = 127; i >= 1; i--)
    {
        bin[i] = bin[i - 1];
    }

    bin[0] = (char)(48 + bit);  

    return bin;
}
```

The problem is that in the end the value of `x0`, `y0` and `z0` will be the same of `dT0`.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: All relevant code is inside functions (hexToBinary and lfsr) you didn't post...

Comment: Please show the `lfsr` function. It's very likely that you are returning a pointer to a local variable (which you should not do).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You return the argument `bin` from the `lfsr` function. This pointer will always be the same. So what you are really doing is making all variables point to the same location.

So when you do

```
y0 = lfsr(x0);
```

you make `y0` point to what `x0` is already pointing to. And when you do

```
z0 = lfsr(y0);
```

you make `z0` point to what `y0` is pointing to, and as it's already pointing to what `x0` is pointing to then this is the same as making `z0` point to the same as well.

If you print out the *pointers* you will see them all have the exact same value.

---

A simple way of fixing this is to make all the variables (`x0`, `y0` etc.) arrays, and then pass them in as arguments.

Comment: Oh, I understand. Can you tell me how can i avoid this?

Comment: @arturataide Make the variables arrays instead, that you pass in as argument to the function.

Answer (score 0):

first malloc memory for *x0,*y0,*z0,*dT0

then use a temp pointer for the returns of your functions.

like

```
char *pTmp

pTmp= hexToBinary(seed);
```

then memcpy the contents of pTmp to x0,y0,z0,dT0 accordingly.

```
memcpy(x0,pTmp,size);
```

you should find some way to figure out the size of the file.

Comment: The size of the file is always 128bit. Thank you.